# how to create a mount config in the root directory (/) in Docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to create a docker volume in the root directory. When I try to run docker compose, I'm getting the following error :-     `Cannot create container for service sample-volume: b'invalid volume specification: \'Volume1:/:rw\': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid specification: destination can\'t be \'/\''` 
How do I go about mounting the volume in the root directory?

I went through this Github issue :- `https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3285`. I'm still unable to resolve the issue.

Docker compose command used :- `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml`

Comment: please, share your docker-compose file

Answer (score 2):

If you could successfully run **docker run -v /host/path:/ image** then it would cause the contents of **/host/path** to be the only thing visible in the container; it would be the container’s root. As a result, you will not able to run the os inside the container.

Provide the target directory/filename.
e.g. /host/path:/root/path